# why I'm getting `null` when dispatching an action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

console.log(bankStore.getState().balance);
I get 0 which is expected.

Then I have a container which passes props to `<BankApp />` component (as I understand):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    balance: state.balance
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onDeposit: amount => dispatch(depositIntoAccount(amount)),
  };
};
const BankAppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BankApp);
```

This is my `<BankApp />` component which receives props from BankAppContainer:

```
class BankApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    amount: 0
  };

  onInputChange = e => {
    const amount = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ amount });
  };

  onDeposit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onDeposit({
      amount: parseFloat(this.state.amount, 10)
    });
    this.setState({ amount: 0 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              placeholder="add num"
              value={this.state.amount}
            />
            <br />
            <div>
              <br />
              <button onClick={this.onDeposit}>deposit</button>
              <button>withdraw</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Here is my action creator for depositIntoAccount :

```
export const depositIntoAccount = amount => ({
  type: "DEPOSIT_INTO_ACCOUNT",
  amount
});
```

and this is my app reducer:

```
export default (state = { balance: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DEPOSIT_INTO_ACCOUNT":
      return {
        balance: state.balance + parseFloat(action.amount)
      };
```

When I click on `deposit` I'm dispatching depositIntoAccount action but my `console.log(bankStore.getState().balance)` is now `Object {balance: null}`

Comment: how have you set up the store, root reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending in an object by mistake in the action.

```
this.props.onDeposit({
  amount: parseFloat(this.state.amount, 10)
});
```

This should be

```
this.props.onDeposit(parseFloat(this.state.amount, 10));
```